# List comprehension in IPython Notebook returning [None, None, None...]

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension, jupyter-notebook

I am looking to generate a list of enumerated strings using list comprehension within an IPython Notebook. It works, but gives me a strange output that I do not understand.

```
cols = []
[cols.append('Value'+str(hour)) for hour in xrange(1,25)]
```

After running the cell, `cols` returns the proper list `[Value1,Value2...Value24]`, but within my notebook, I receive an output list of 24 `None`. [Example photo](https://imgur.com/a/d9flq)

The code works, but the strange output makes me feel like I've done something wrong, and it looks sloppy. Why do I get this output, and is there a way I can get rid of it?

Comment: Well, what does `cols.append` return? `None`, right? So that's where your `None`s are coming from: you told Python to put the result of `cols.append()` into a list, 24 times.

Comment: Because a list comprehension creates a new list. In your case, a list of the return values of `append`, which happens to be `None`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `None`s that you see in the list, are the result of evaluating the function call `cols.append('Value'+str(hour))`. You see the resulting `cols` with the right entries, because they get appended, but the list being generated in this list comprehension method, actually only consists of results from evaluating `append()` many times.

Instead try `cols = ['Value'+str(hour) for hour in xrange(1,25)]`

Comment: Alrighty that did it. Probably should've been obvious, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`cols.append(value)` appends the value to `cols` but returns `None`, it doesn't return `cols` with the appended value, so after your code, cols has the content that you want, but you could do it better with this:

```
cols = ['Value'+str(hour) for hour in xrange(1,25)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the the list comprehension you have that will return a list of None. Instead you want the actual list cols after the appending was done. For this, all you have to do is replace the first element of the dummy list with your list comprehension as follows:

```
[[cols.append('Value'+str(hour)) for hour in xrange(1,25)], cols][1]
```

or simply:

```
[('value'+str(x)) for x in xrange(1,25)]
```